# Nutcracker in space, torque provided by thruster vs by reaction force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

In the following image, a nutcracker is floating in space. Attached to points B and C are two thrusters (not shown). Each of them provides an equal force horizontally inwards, shown by the red arrows. As a result, torque will be experienced at the fulcrum (A), and help to crack the nut.

**EDIT: it is better to think about this problem without the nut. That way, the nutcracker can "close".**

[image]

In the next image, another space nutcracker is shown. Here, there is only one thruster (at C). An immovable surface is shown on the left, which is touching B.

[image]

The surface provides a reaction force against B, such that the situation is equivalent to the first image.

What I'm having trouble understanding is how this reaction force can provide a torque on the green segment around point A. My confusion arises because in my mind, I have it set that in order for the green segment to experience a torque around A, it must rotate around A. And in order for it to rotate around A, point B must move (in this case, point B must move to the right, while tracing an arc).

But because point B is fixed (the immovable object is always touching B, and the immovable object doesn't move), this can't happen.

I figure it's something to do with how motion is relative (i.e. A moving closer to B is the same as B moving closer to A), but it doesn't sit well with my mechanical intuition of what a torque is.

Can someone help guide me through how to think about this properly?

Comment: Why cannot $A$ move closer to the wall?

Comment: I never said A couldn't move closer to the wall. I said that B couldn't move to the right.

Comment: If $A$ moves closer to the wall as does $C$ then the nutcracker "works" and $B$ does not move.

Comment: Right, but I'm having trouble understanding how the reaction force of the wall causes a torque to be experienced by the green segment around B, since B does not move rightwards. In the first image, B moves rightwards, and all makes sense in my head. In the second image, the situation is equivalent in terms of torque experienced at A, but also different somehow.

Comment: The green bar has two extra forces acing on it to the left due to the nut and the pivot.  Those three forces produce the rotation of the green bar.

Comment: Ok, suppose we remove the nut, so the nutcracker can actually close (this was an oversight in my original framing of the problem).

I can see how the force in the pivot provides a (counterclockwise) torque of the green bar around point B. This makes perfect sense, and indeed, point A actually moves leftwards as a reflection of this rotation.

But i'm specifically talking about the counterclockwise torque of the green bar around point A. Clearly, the reaction force of the wall against B provides a torque of the green bar around point A, yet B does not move rightwards.

Comment: The point about which you are calculating the torque, $A$, moves.

Comment: The location of B is fixed, but that doesn't mean it's rotation is.  C & A will move towards B.  Bar A-B will rotate around point B (since it cannot translate there).  From the perspective of A, B does move to the right.  From the perspective of B or the wall, A moves left.  You could analyze the first situation the exact same way.  Take a nutcracker and hold one arm stationary while only pivoting the other.  As far as the nut is concerned, both sides are turning into it.

Comment: aye, that makes some sense to me (the relative motion). But it seems that something has gone awry _causally_. The wall is exerting a force at B, and yet point B isn't moving.  It's as there were two boulders separated by a distance in space. And a force is exerted on the first boulder in the direction of the second. And instead of the first boulder moving towards the second one, the second one is _pulled_ towards the first. I'm having that same cognitive reaction here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to think about torque. That only complicates the situation. You only need to think about the forces at B and C and the work they do, which is the same in both cases.

The thrusters at B and C both do work to crack the nut. If the initial distance between them is $2x$ and each thruster supplies force $F$ then when they meet in the middle the work done by each is $Fx$ so the total work done is $2Fx$.

When the thruster at B is replaced by a wall, the wall also exerts force $F$ in reaction to the force $F$ applied in the opposite direction by the thruster at C. The force at the wall does not move through any distance, so it does no work. However, now points A and C move towards the wall, A by $x$ and C by $2x$. In this case the only work is done by thruster C, and is $2Fx$. So the total work done is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sammy. That's interesting. So the two scenarios are not equivalent as far as the thruster at C is concerned.

The reason I devised this example is because I'm trying to get better at analyzing forces and torques in multi-jointed systems that are rotating around multiple joints simultaneously. 

It occurred to me that reaction forces from the "ground" can cause torques at certain joints, and therefore rotations.  But I run into the conceptual problem illustrated here.